# Calculating the vertical gradient of 2D image causes strange output

Tags: c++, image-processing

I want to apply a simple derive/gradient filter, [-1, 0, 1], to an image from a .ppm file.

The raw binary data from the .ppm file is read into a one-dimensional array:

```cpp
uint8_t* raw_image_data;
size_t n_rows, n_cols, depth;

// Open the file as an input binary file
std::ifstream file;
file.open("test_image.ppm", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
if (!file.is_open())  { /* error */ }

std::string temp_line;
// Check that it's a valid P6 file
if (!(std::getline(file, temp_line) && temp_line == "P6")) {}
// Then skip all the comments (lines that begin with a #)
while (std::getline(file, temp_line) && temp_line.at(0) == '#');

// Try read in the info about the number of rows and columns
try {
    n_rows = std::stoi(temp_line.substr(0, temp_line.find(' ')));
    n_cols = std::stoi(temp_line.substr(temp_line.find(' ')+1,temp_line.size()));
    std::getline(file, temp_line);
    depth = std::stoi(temp_line);
} catch (const std::invalid_argument & e) { /* stoi has failed */}

// Allocate memory and read in all image data from ppm
raw_image_data = new uint8_t[n_rows*n_cols*3];
file.read((char*)raw_image_data, n_rows*n_cols*3);
file.close();
```

I then read a grayscale image from the data into a two-dimensional array, called `image_grayscale`:

```cpp
uint8_t** image_grayscale;
image_grayscale = new uint8_t*[n_rows];
for (size_t i = 0; i < n_rows; ++i) {
    image_grayscale[i] = new uint8_t[n_cols];
}

// Convert linear array of raw image data to 2d grayscale image
size_t counter = 0;
for (size_t r = 0; r < n_rows; ++r) {
    for (size_t c = 0; c < n_cols; ++c) {
        image_grayscale[r][c] = 0.21*raw_image_data[counter]
            + 0.72*raw_image_data[counter+1]
            + 0.07*raw_image_data[counter+2];
        counter += 3;
    }
}
```

I want to write the resulting filtered image to another two-dimensional array, `gradient_magnitude`:

```cpp
uint32_t** gradient_magnitude;
// Allocate memory
gradient_magnitude = new uint32_t*[n_rows];
for (size_t i = 0; i < n_rows; ++i) {
    gradient_magnitude[i] = new uint32_t[n_cols];
}

// Filtering operation
int32_t grad_h, grad_v;
for (int r = 1; r < n_rows-1; ++r) {
    for (int c = 1; c < n_cols-1; ++c) {
        grad_h = image_grayscale[r][c+1] - image_grayscale[r][c-1];
        grad_v = image_grayscale[r+1][c] - image_grayscale[r-1][c];
        gradient_magnitude[r][c] = std::sqrt(pow(grad_h, 2) + pow(grad_v, 2));
    }
}
```

Finally, I write the filtered image to a .ppm output.

```cpp
std::ofstream out;
out.open("output.ppm", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

// ppm header
out << "P6\n" << n_rows << " " << n_cols << "\n" << "255\n";

// Write data to file
for (int r = 0; r < n_rows; ++r) {
    for (int c = 0; c < n_cols; ++c) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            out.write((char*) &gradient_magnitude[r][c],1);
        }
    }
}
out.close();
```

The output image, however, is a mess.

When I simply set `grad_v = 0;` in the loop (i.e. solely calculate the horizontal gradient), the output is seemingly correct:

[image: Horizontal Gradient]

When I instead set `grad_h = 0;` (i.e. solely calculate the vertical gradient), the output is strange:

[image: Vertical Gradient]

It seems like part of the image has been circularly shifted, but I cannot understand why. Moreover, I have tried with many images and the same issue occurs.

Can anyone see any issues? Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you maybe load an RGB image? You’d have three values for each pixel, rather than one. So the neighbor pixel below is 3*width bytes away, not width. Your output is consistent with that difference (three vertical bands across the image).

Comment: If you want a more detailed help, read [mre], then [edit] your question accordingly. It currently doesn’t have enough information to write an answer.

Comment: Could you give us the representation of your input image?

Comment: Apologies for not including more code–––I was worried about adding too much. I have updated the question with a minimal example. I hope it's fine? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the range of the gradient magnitude? Why are you using 32 bit integers and saving only the least significant byte?

Comment: @CostantinoGrana the image has an 8-bit colour depth, which is why `image_grayscale` uses 8-bit unsigned integers. The maximum difference between two pixels is thus 255, and the maximum gradient magnitude is sqrt((255^2)+(255^2)) = 360.6. I was using 32-bit integers for the gradient magnitude just to be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first clue is that the image looks circularly shifted. This hints that strides are wrong. The core of your problem is simple:

```cpp
    n_rows = std::stoi(temp_line.substr(0, temp_line.find(' ')));
    n_cols = std::stoi(temp_line.substr(temp_line.find(' ')+1,temp_line.size()));
```

but in the [documentation](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) you can read:

> Each PPM image consists of the following:
>
> 1. A "magic number" for identifying the file type. A ppm image's magic number is the two
>      characters "P6".
> 2. Whitespace (blanks, TABs, CRs, LFs).
> 3. A **width**, formatted as ASCII characters in decimal.
> 4. Whitespace.
> 5. A **height**, again in ASCII decimal.
>
> [...]

Width is columns, height is rows. So that's the classical error that you get when implementing image processing stuff: swapping rows and columns.

From a didactic point of view, why are you doing this mistake? My guess: poor debugging tools. After making a working example from your question (effort that I would have saved if you had provided a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), I run to the end of image loading and used Image Watch to see the content of your image with `@mem(raw_image_data, UINT8, 3, n_cols, n_rows, n_cols*3)`. Result:

[image: wrong result]

Ok, let's try to swap them: `@mem(raw_image_data, UINT8, 3, n_rows, n_cols, n_rows*3)`. Result:

[image: correct result]

Much better. Unfortunately I don't know how to specify RGB instead of BGR in Image Watch @mem pseudo command, so the wrong colors.

Then we come back to your code: please compile with all warnings on. Then I'd use more of the `std::stream` features for parsing your input and less `std::stoi()` or `find()`. Avoid memory allocation by using `std::vector` and make a (possibly template) class for images. Even if you stick to your pointer to pointer, don't make multiple `new` for each row: make a single new for the pointer at row 0, and have the other pointers point to it:

```
    uint8_t** image_grayscale = new uint8_t*[n_rows];
    image_grayscale[0] = new uint8_t[n_rows*n_cols];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n_rows; ++i) {
        image_grayscale[i] = image_grayscale[i - 1] + n_cols;
    }
```

Same effect, but easier to deallocate and to manage as a single piece of memory. For example, saving as a PGM becomes:

```
    {
        std::ofstream out("output.pgm", std::ios::binary);
        out << "P5\n" << n_rows << " " << n_cols << "\n" << "255\n";
        out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(image_grayscale[0]), n_rows*n_cols);
    }
```

Fill your borders! Using the single allocation style I showed you you can do it as:

```
    uint32_t** gradient_magnitude = new uint32_t*[n_rows];
    gradient_magnitude[0] = new uint32_t[n_rows*n_cols];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n_rows; ++i) {
        gradient_magnitude[i] = gradient_magnitude[i - 1] + n_cols;
    }
    std::fill_n(gradient_magnitude[0], n_rows*n_cols, 0);
```

Finally the gradient magnitude is an integer value between 0 and 360 (you used a `uint32_t`). Then you save only the least significant byte of it! Of course it's *wrong*. You need to map from [0,360] to [0,255]. How? You can saturate (if greater than 255 set to 255) or apply a linear scaling (`*255/360`). Of course you can do also other things, but it's not important.

Here you can see the result on a zoomed version of the three cases: saturate, scale, only LSB (wrong):
[image: Comparison of different saving modalities]
With the wrong version you see dark pixels where the value should be higer than 255.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for all of that! Very silly error on my part. This relates to a university assignment, and the documentation we were given swapped the order of the rows and cols, and we were using square images, so it mostly went unnoticed–––I should've followed up though. Also, thanks for the other advice. Regarding the provided MCVE, should I have given more or less code? Just so that I can know for next time. Thanks!

Comment: Your code was nearly there. Next time provide a full file that can be copy and pasted into an editor and run/debugged. So it takes a second to test your code, without going through the pain of adding the right includes and performing multiple copy/paste.

Comment: Will do! Thanks again.